# Why might 'remix build' not auto-generate the build directory and its contents in my Remix.js project and how do I fix it?

Tags: remix.run

I'm encountering an issue in my Remix.js project where running the "remix build" command does not automatically generate the build directory along with its contents, including the index.js file.

I tried deleting the *build* and *public/build* directories and ran `yarn run remix build` again. This generates the *public/build* directory but its generated content is the same every time, no routes or _shared subdirectory, just a bunch of fonts in the _assets subdirectory and the `build` directory and its contents isn't created at all.

Comment: That seems really odd. Have you tried creating a new project and moving the app folder over?